# I have to remove the peninsula route everytime when i run the project on my home page

Tags: zend-framework2

An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:

> Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException

File:

> C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php:328

Message:

> Connect Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'registration'

Stack trace:

```
#0 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo.php(249): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection->connect()
#1 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Sql\Sql.php(120): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo->createStatement()
#2 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(232): Zend\Db\Sql\Sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#3 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(208): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->executeSelect(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#4 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(195): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->selectWith(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#5 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\module\Peninsula\src\Peninsula\Model\RegistrationTable.php(22): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->select()
#6 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\module\Peninsula\src\Peninsula\Controller\PeninsulaController.php(53): Peninsula\Model\RegistrationTable->fetchAll()
#7 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): Peninsula\Controller\PeninsulaController->indexAction()
#8 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#13 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#15 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(313): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#17 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\public\index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#18 {main}
```

Previous exceptions:

> PDOException

File:

> C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php:320

Message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'registration'

Stack trace:

```
#0 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php(320): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=re...', 'root', '', Array)
#1 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo.php(249): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection->connect()
#2 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Sql\Sql.php(120): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo->createStatement()
#3 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(232): Zend\Db\Sql\Sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#4 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(208): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->executeSelect(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#5 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(195): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->selectWith(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#6 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\module\Peninsula\src\Peninsula\Model\RegistrationTable.php(22): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->select()
#7 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\module\Peninsula\src\Peninsula\Controller\PeninsulaController.php(53): Peninsula\Model\RegistrationTable->fetchAll()
#8 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): Peninsula\Controller\PeninsulaController->indexAction()
#9 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#13 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#14 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#15 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#16 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#17 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(313): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#18 C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\oscar&rose\public\index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#19 {main}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please format your question; this is impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so there is this error "Unknown database 'registration'". So, maybe the database 'registration' is unknown. :-)